# How to enable rabbitmq_management in kubernetes manifest?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have the following manifest where I succeed in deploying RabbitMQ pod, service and ingress:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: X 
spec:
  serviceName: rabbitmq
  # replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:v01
        ports:
          - containerPort: 15672
            name: rabbitmq-mgmnt
          - containerPort: 5672
            name: rabbitmq
        env:
          - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
            value: "..."
          - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
            value: "..."
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5672
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5672
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 5
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 800m
            ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
            memory: 1Gi
          limits:
            cpu: 8
            ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
            memory: 16Gi

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  ports:
  - name: rabbitmq
    port: 15672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15672
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq

---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: X
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
  - match: Host(`Y`) 
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: rabbitmq
      port: 15672
  tls: {}
```

Once I have all deployed, I have to exec in pod to enter the command : rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management in order to have RabbitMQ Management UI access.

I would like to have this command in the manifest, I tried :

- initContainers
- lifecycle

  ```
    lifecycle:
       postStart:
         exec:
           command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "if ! rabbitmq-plugins list -E | grep -q rabbitmq_management; then rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management; fi"]
     command:
       - "/bin/sh"
       - "-c"
       - |
         rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
  ```

OR

```
 lifecycle:
   postStart:
     exec:
       command: ["rabbitmq-plugins", "enable", "rabbitmq_management"]
```

OR command or args under "image:..." line.

I have crash loop backoff container.

What is the best solution to have the command rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management executed through the manifest ? I guess after pod is deployed/ready/live

Comment: do you know that there is the k8s operator? https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator

Comment: What are the benefits of using cluster-operator ?

Comment: To automate the configurations